# 401 Unauthorized access for Github API using HttpBuilder (Groovy)

Tags: authentication, groovy, http-status-code-401, github-api, httpbuilder

I wrote a Groovy script to manage some organization repos on Github.  It was working great until several weeks ago, when the same script started failing.  Maybe Github changed some aspect of their API?  Or maybe I'm doing something stupid.  I've narrowed the problem down to this simplified example (requires a valid [github](https://github.com/) account):

```java
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6' )

import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

String username = System.console().readLine 'Username: '
char[] password = System.console().readPassword 'Password: '

def github = new HTTPBuilder('https://api.github.com')
github.auth.basic username, password.toString()
def emails = github.get(path: '/user/emails', 
    headers: ['Accept': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'Apache HTTPClient'])
println emails
```

Output:

> $ groovy GithubHttpBuilderTest.groovy
>   Username: username
>   Password: 
>   Caught: groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
>   groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
>     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.defaultFailureHandler(HTTPBuilder.java:652)
>     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:508)
>     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:292)
>     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:262)
>     at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$get.call(Unknown Source)
>     at GithubHttpBuilderTest.run(GithubHttpBuilderTest.groovy:10)

Using the same credentials, curl works:

```bsh
$ curl -u username https://api.github.com/user/emails
```

Output:

> [
>     "username@example.com"
>   ]

Am I missing something on how to properly authenticate to the Github API using HttpBuilder?

> EDIT: fixed an error in my code, where I treated `System.console().readPassword` as a String instead of its actual return type: char[].  Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `github.auth.basic username, password` doesn't seem to work, you need to set it manually:

```
String userPassBase64 = "$username:$password".toString().bytes.encodeBase64()    
def github = new HTTPBuilder('https://api.github.com')
def emails = github.get(path: '/user/emails', headers: ["Authorization": "Basic $userPassBase64"])
```

Comment: Thanks.  It was a combination of a mistake on my part (treating a password from the console as a String when it is actually a char[]) and the fact that github.auth.basic doesn't seem to work.  It's working now.  Thanks!