# HTTP basic authorisation ERROR 401. showing , but I am entering right email and password

Tags: python, data-science

```
import requests

from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

a=requests.get('https://api.github.com/user',auth=HTTPBasicAuth('email','pass'))
print(a.status_code)
```

I am entering right GitHub email and password but getting error 401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [401 Unauthorized access for Github API using HttpBuilder (Groovy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646734/401-unauthorized-access-for-github-api-using-httpbuilder-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

Username: password is not longer supported by GitHub for API https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens